# "illegal scope" error when trying to get all user playlists from another user in spotifyR

Tags: r, json, spotify

I'm trying to obtain all the yearly Billboard Top 100 songs from the earliest possible year, for a data analysis project. I am using R with the spotifyR package.

I thought a good approach would be to find a user who has compiled many playlists with all the top 100 songs, and then use that list as a starting point to get all the songs and their spotify song id inside of them. I found a user who has a set of playlists fitting exactly what I need (e.g. "Billboard top 100 1964", "Billboard top 100 1965", etc).

The spotifyR package provides a function for this, called get_user_playlists whih requires as argument the user ID along with other arguments (limit, offset, authorization = get_authorization_code(), include_meta_info).

When I try to use that code, I get a request for an authorization code which I do not have and a chrome tab opens saying only "illegal scope". I have already set my client ID and secret, saving the token to an object. I can access albums and songs in spotify without any issue but for some reason I cannot get a list of the playlists for an individual user (and I can perfectly visualize those playlists and user in the spotify app)

How can I get that authorization code in order to get that set of playlists?

Comment: Without seeing any of your code, see if anything here will help https://www.reddit.com/r/RStudio/comments/dz8ala/how_to_access_spotify_api_from_package_spotifyr/